# Python: How to extract rows from a csv file based on multiple criteria specified in a tuple

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I have a very large .csv file (10GB) and want to extract rows based on different criteria in a tuple.
The fourth column of each row contains IPAdd
I need to extract only the rows with specific IP.

I'm new to python and would like to know how can I iterate over each tuple IP and write them into the WYE_Data.csv file.

The content sample of the CSV file is;

```
xxx,1234,abc,199.199.1.1,1,fghy,xxx   
xxx,1234,abc,10.10.1.1,1,fghy,xxx   
xxx,1234,abc,144.122.1.1,1,fghy,xxx   
xxx,1234,abc,50.200.50.32,1,fghy,xxx

import csv   
customers = csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')    
## This is the line I'm having         issues with   
IPAdd = ('199.199.1.1' or '144.122.1.1' or '22.22.36.22')
csvout = csv.writer(open('WYE_Data.csv', 'ab')) 

for customer in customers:   
    if customer[3] == IPAdd:    
        csvout.writerow(customer)
```

Comment: You can use `grep` to filter the file before it reaches Python.

Comment: You might want to consider changing this csv to a real database if you're going to be doing complex queries against it. 10gb csv is insane!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use a list of the values you want to match for IP.

```
ips = ['199.199.1.1', '144.122.1.1', '22.22.36.22']
```

Then you can say:

```
if customer[3] in ips:
```

Comment: Actually I would use a `set` or `frozenset`, since the `in` operator for those is much faster and order doesn't matter.

Comment: Using the syntax indicated by ChipJust worked fine.... The queries hangs on the database as the result-set is always too large for database. So I prefer using python to extract what I need and log it into another csv. Thank you foe the help..

Comment: @user1449309: I would look into new database software. This is not a large dataset.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

look_for = set(['199.199.1.1', '144.122.1.1', '22.22.36.22'])

with open('data.csv','rb') as inf, open('wye_data.csv','wb') as outf:
    incsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
    outcsv = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',')
    outcsv.writerows(row for row in incsv if row[3] in look_for)
```